# Vuescan + Ubuntu 19.04

Tags: scanner

Ever since the latest version of Ubuntu came out (19.04) Vuescan will not run, it worked fine with any previous version. I have contacted Vuescan and they are astonished as well.
Simple Scan is a bit too slow or should I say very slow, if either Simple Scan will get much faster or Vuescan will run with 19.04 I will be much happier :)
I will appreciate your help very much, thanks in advance.

Torres.

Comment: when you start it from command line does it give any notifications that show there is a problem?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution:

```
sudo apt-get install libgtk2.0-0
```